# I want to convert Json file to csv file using Pyhton

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I have problem when i convert json file to csv
i convert my csv file to json and it work
but when i convert json file to csv file it don't work!

HERE MY PYTHON CODE

```
   with open('orders.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
 
    order_data = data['orders']

    # now we will open a file for writing
    data_file = open('data_file.csv', 'w')

    # create the csv writer object
    csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file)

    # Counter variable used for writing
    # headers to the CSV file
    count = 0

    for ord in order_data:
        if count == 0:

            # Writing headers of CSV file
            header = ord.keys()
            csv_writer.writerow(header)
            count += 1

        # Writing data of CSV file
        csv_writer.writerow(ord.values())

    data_file.close()
```

and the output is like this

[image]

there null row on the csv file how to handle this problem?

and here the json file

[image]

Comment: Try opening the csv file in a text editor like notepad and see if it also has empty rows there or if this is only an excel issue.

Comment: Also: Try making your `with` blocks as short as possible, i.e. only read the data within the first `with` block and do everything else on top level.

Comment: i try to open it on notepad and also has empty rows . it is not excel issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3 the required syntax changed and the csv module now works with text mode `'w'`, but also needs the `newline=''` (empty string) parameter to suppress Windows line translation.

```
with open('/pythonwork/thefile_subset11.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
```